# How to compile java in 1.6 or older version without changing the classpath and path? We only need to use command line to execute the same

Tags: java, command

How to compile java in 1.6 or older version without changing the classpath and path? We only need to use command line to execute the same.
like :

```
javac var -1.6 Hello.java
java Hello
```

Comment: i don't know the exact solution

Comment: in C drive both jdk and jre are available 1.6 and older version & newest version also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to compile java in 1.6 or older version without changing the classpath and path

```
  javac -source 1.6 Test.java
```

this will help you to understand by using

```
javac -help

-source <release>    Provide source compatibility with specified release
```

Comment: there is no need to use _-target 1.6_

Answer (score 0):

To compile your code and target Java 1.6 you can specify `target` and `source` compiler options. Something like,

```
javac -target 1.6 -source 1.6 Hello.java
```

The `javac -help` explains,

> ```
> -source <release>    Provide source compatibility with specified release
> -target <release>    Generate class files for specific VM version
> ```